# Horizontal Nav Bar Sub Navs Wrapping Down instead of using space behind(left) of it

Tags: html, css, nav

So the problem I have is that if I select the last option on my nav bar, because the drop down has so many options, it exceeds the length left of the nav bar and wraps underneath, creating a grid of options 2x2.

I would much prefer if it used the space to the left rather than wrapping down. how can I make this possible.

```css
nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
nav ul {
  color: white;
  background: #787878;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #787878 0%, #272727 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #787878 0%, #272727 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #787878 0%, #272727 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background: #A8A8A8;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
  background: #505050;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #A8A8A8;
}
nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/p/">Players</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Wonderkids</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cheap Players</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Player Comparisons</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/c/">Clubs</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Club Info</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Transfer Budgets</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sugar Daddys</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/s/">Downloads</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tactics</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Shortlists</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Various Shortlists</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Positional Shortlists</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Staff Shortlists</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/g/">Write-Ups</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/p/">Social</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Youtube</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Affiliates</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/aboutus/">About Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: why not letting the <li> unwrapping it down vertically as intended?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the submenu is aligned on the left edge of the parent item in the main menu. Let's align the submenu on the right edge of the main menu.

1. Add class `ul-right` to the corresponding `<ul>`.
2. Add CSS-code `nav ul ul.ul-right { right: 0; }`.

Check the result:

```css
nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
nav ul {
  color: white;
  background: #787878;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #787878 0%, #272727 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #787878 0%, #272727 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #787878 0%, #272727 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background: #A8A8A8;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
  background: #505050;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul.ul-right {
  right: 0;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #A8A8A8;
}
nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/p/">Players</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Wonderkids</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cheap Players</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Player Comparisons</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/c/">Clubs</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Club Info</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Transfer Budgets</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sugar Daddys</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/s/">Downloads</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tactics</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Shortlists</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Various Shortlists</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Positional Shortlists</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Staff Shortlists</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/g/">Write-Ups</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/p/">Social</a>
      <ul class="ul-right">
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Youtube</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Affiliates</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/aboutus/">About Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, excellent, dont suppose you have a solution to another nav problem I am having, the ul ul ul does not appear where I would like it

Comment: @MattDempsey Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is a library of answers. [Do accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answerssomeone-answers) if it helped you. Do ask new question if you have another issue.